# Keyframe animation back to initial state

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I did a slow infinite `CSS3` animation. It animates from `top:0;` to `top:40px;`. The error is when the animate ends, it jumps to the start point. I think it should jump with `ease`or `ease-in` but that's not happening. I tried a lot to fix this, but I failed.

I need the return transition to have an `ease-in` effect.

My Code:

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
/** Down Slow Animation **/

@-webkit-keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite;
  animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is just an alternative solution**

Just add `alternate`  ant the end of `animation`.

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
/** Down Slow Animation **/

@-webkit-keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@keyframes downSlow {
  from { top: 0px; }
  to { top: 40px; }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

The same code can be reduce to

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
  top: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes downSlow {
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes downSlow {
  to { top: 40px; }
}
@keyframes downSlow {
  to { top: 40px; }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;
  
  -webkit-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

A much better approach would be to use `translate` this way your element will not interfere with other DOM elements

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes downSlow {
  to { transform: translateY(40px) }
}
@-moz-keyframes downSlow {
  to { transform: translateY(40px) }
}
@keyframes downSlow {
  to { transform: translateY(40px) }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;

  -webkit-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
  animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

But again you can reduce this with [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) frind a [cdn here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/prefixfree)

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

@keyframes downSlow {
  to { transform: translateY(40px) }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;
  animation: downSlow 1.5s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

at the end set speed/2

```css
span {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

@keyframes downSlow {
  to { transform: translateY(40px) }
}
.down-slow {
  position: relative;
  animation: downSlow .7s infinite alternate forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="down-slow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i></span>
```

REF: [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Comment: nice alternatives! +1

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting `alternate` and `translate` which improves the performance.